# Как передать импортированному классу в контекст выходы компонент Vue

Tags: vue.js

Как сделать конектсом вызова в экземпляре класса vue компонент?
К примеру мне нужно вызвать какой то метод экземпляра класса в нём используется this, нужно чтобы this всегда ссылался на методы или свойства компонента .
Пример ниже

```
// test.js

class TestClass {
  methodLog() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const test = new TestClass();
export default test;


    //  VUE 
    
    import test from "./test.js";
    
    data: () => {
      name: 'Ivan',
    },
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/viktor-chernenko/pen/xxdXLzb

Comment: `const vsegdaSsylalsya = TestClass.prototype.methodLog.bind(yourVueCmpntInstance);`

Comment: Экспорт в примере неадекватен вопросу... т.к. экспортируется экземпляр, а не "класс".